# Passing list values for index slicing python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function capable of taking in positions to return the character values at those positions later.

This program works as attended:

```
txt = "who makes bromocriptinei am wondering what company makes the drug bromocriptine, i need it for a mass i have on my pituitary gland and the cost just keeps raising. i cannot ever buy a full prescription because of the price and i was told if i get a hold of the maker of the drug sometimes they offer coupons or something to help me afford the medicine. if i buy 10 pills in which i have to take 2 times a day it costs me 78.00. and that is how i have to buy them.  thanks."

positions = [txt[10: 24], txt[66: 79]]
# ['bromocriptinei', 'bromocriptine']
```

I'm trying to have something a bit more reusable as the positions used `(10: 24), (66:79)` can change. I tried passing the whole coordinate value as a condition wrapped inside a function, as I thought it would be better for reusability:

```
txt = "who makes bromocriptinei am wondering what company makes the drug bromocriptine, i need it for a mass i have on my pituitary gland and the cost just keeps raising. i cannot ever buy a full prescription because of the price and i was told if i get a hold of the maker of the drug sometimes they offer coupons or something to help me afford the medicine. if i buy 10 pills in which i have to take 2 times a day it costs me 78.00. and that is how i have to buy them.  thanks."


coordinates = [[10, 24], [66, 79]]

def string_to_find(coordinates, txt):
    position_string = [txt[coordinates]]
    
string_to_find(x[0], health_questions[0])
```

This throws a type error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, due to the coordinates being passed as string values. I find this method could be more efficient and would allow for further development, like looping through a list of coordinates:

```
for x in range(len(coordinates)):
    word_match = string_to_find(x, txt)
```

Is it possible to pass the list elements as the positions of characters?

Comment: You could unpack them and pass them as indexes.

Comment: Or you could just do `txt[coordinates[0]: coordinates[1]]`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA could you clarify on what you mean by `txt[coordinates[0]: coordinates[1]]` . Passing this would still throw a TypeError?

Comment: How about changing `coordinates = [10, 24]` to `coordinates = slice(10, 24)` and then using `txt[coordinates]` ?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, this partially solves the question. However, it creates the need to convert the list of coordinates to slices instead, which will lead back to a similar issue.

Comment: Your example has co-ordinates as list with 2 elements only. You could do `txt[coordinates[0]:coordinates[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
coordinates = [[10, 24], [66, 79]]
print([txt[i0:i1] for i0, i1 in coordinates])
# Outputs ['bromocriptinei', 'bromocriptine']
```